# how do i add activites in tabbar? please help me

Tags: android

this is my code which i follow from code.google.com this link    http://code.google.com/p/android-playground/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FSwipeyTabsSample
  just tell me how do i add activites in this application?  is show same activity in all tabs

```
                public class SwipeyTabsSampleActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final String [] TITLES = {
            "CATEGORIES",
            "FEATURED",
            "TOP PAID",
            "TOP FREE",
            "TOP GROSSING",
            "TOP NEW PAID",
            "TOP NEW FREE",
            "TRENDING",
    };

    private SwipeyTabs mTabs;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_swipeytab);

            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            mTabs = (SwipeyTabs) findViewById(R.id.swipeytabs);

            SwipeyTabsPagerAdapter adapter = new SwipeyTabsPagerAdapter(this,
                            getSupportFragmentManager());
            mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            mTabs.setAdapter(adapter);
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(mTabs);
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }

    private class SwipeyTabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
                    SwipeyTabsAdapter {

            private final Context mContext;

            public SwipeyTabsPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
                    super(fm);

                    this.mContext = context;
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                    return SwipeyTabFragment.newInstance(TITLES[position]);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                    return TITLES.length;
            }

            public TextView getTab(final int position, SwipeyTabs root) {
                    TextView view = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                                    R.layout.swipey_tab_indicator, root, false);
                    view.setText(TITLES[position]);
                    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
                            }
                    });

                    return view;
            }

    }

 }





               public interface SwipeyTabsAdapter {

    /**
     * Return the number swipey tabs. Needs to be aligned with the number of
     * items in your {@link PagerAdapter}.
     *
     * @return
     */
    int getCount();

    /**
     * Build {@link TextView} to diplay as a swipey tab.
     *
     * @param position the position of the tab
     * @param root the root view
     * @return
     */
    TextView getTab(int position, SwipeyTabs root);

}







                    public class SwipeyTabs extends ViewGroup implements 
     OnPageChangeListener {

    protected final String TAG = "SwipeyTabs";

    private SwipeyTabsAdapter mAdapter;

    private int mCurrentPos = -1;

    // height of the bar at the bottom of the tabs
    private int mBottomBarHeight = 2;
    // height of the indicator for the fronted tab
    private int mTabIndicatorHeight = 3;
    // color for the bottom bar, fronted tab
    private int mBottomBarColor = 0xff96aa39;
    // text color for all other tabs
    private int mTextColor = 0xff949494;

    // holds the positions of the fronted tabs
    private int[] mFrontedTabPos;
    // holds the positions of the target position when swiping left
    private int[] mLeftTabPos;
    // holds the positions of the target position when swiping right
    private int[] mRightTabPos;
    // holds the positions of the current position on screen
    private int[] mCurrentTabPos;

    private Paint mCachedTabPaint;

    private int mWidth = -1;

    public SwipeyTabs(Context context) {
            this(context, null);
    }

    public SwipeyTabs(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public SwipeyTabs(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);

            final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                            R.styleable.SwipeyTabs, defStyle, 0);

            mBottomBarColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.SwipeyTabs_bottomBarColor,
                            mBottomBarColor);
            mBottomBarHeight = a.getDimensionPixelSize(
                            R.styleable.SwipeyTabs_bottomBarHeight, 2);
            mTabIndicatorHeight = a.getDimensionPixelSize(
                            R.styleable.SwipeyTabs_tabIndicatorHeight, 3);

            a.recycle();

            init();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the SwipeyTabs {@link ViewGroup}
     */
    private void init() {
            // enable the horizontal fading edges which will be drawn by the parent
            // View
            setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
            setFadingEdgeLength((int) (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 
   35.0f + 0.5f));
            setWillNotDraw(false);

            mCachedTabPaint = new Paint();
            mCachedTabPaint.setColor(mBottomBarColor);
    }

    /**
     * Set the adapter.
     *
     * @param adapter
     */
    public void setAdapter(SwipeyTabsAdapter adapter) {
            if (mAdapter != null) {
                    // TODO: data set observer
            }

            mAdapter = adapter;
            mCurrentPos = -1;
            mFrontedTabPos = null;
            mLeftTabPos = null;
            mRightTabPos = null;
            mCurrentTabPos = null;

            // clean up our childs
            removeAllViews();

            if (mAdapter != null) {
                    final int count = mAdapter.getCount();

                    // add the child text views
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                            addView(mAdapter.getTab(i, this));
                    }

                    mCurrentPos = 0;
                    mFrontedTabPos = new int[count];
                    mLeftTabPos = new int[count];
                    mRightTabPos = new int[count];
                    mCurrentTabPos = new int[count];

                    mWidth = -1;

                    requestLayout();
            }
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the fronted, left and right positions
     *
     * @param forceLayout
     *            force the current positions to the values of the calculated
     *            fronted positions
     */
    private void updateTabPositions(boolean forceLayout) {
            if (mAdapter == null) {
                    return;
            }

            calculateTabPosition(mCurrentPos, mFrontedTabPos);
            calculateTabPosition(mCurrentPos + 1, mLeftTabPos);
            calculateTabPosition(mCurrentPos - 1, mRightTabPos);

            updateEllipsize();

            if (forceLayout) {
                    final int count = mAdapter.getCount();
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                            mCurrentTabPos[i] = mFrontedTabPos[i];
                    }
            }
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the position of the tabs.
     *
     * @param position
     *            the position of the fronted tab
     * @param tabPositions
     *            the array in which to store the result
     */
    private void calculateTabPosition(int position, int[] tabPositions) {
            if (mAdapter == null) {
                    return;
            }

            final int count = mAdapter.getCount();

            if (position >= 0 && position < count) {
                    final int width = getMeasuredWidth();

                    final View centerTab = getChildAt(position);
                    tabPositions[position] = width / 2 - centerTab.getMeasuredWidth()
                                    / 2;
                    for (int i = position - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                            final TextView tab = (TextView) getChildAt(i);
                            if (i == position - 1) {
                                    tabPositions[i] = 0 - tab.getPaddingLeft();
                            } else {
                                    tabPositions[i] = 0 - tab.getMeasuredWidth() - 
    width;
                            }
                            tabPositions[i] = Math.min(tabPositions[i], tabPositions[i 
   + 1]
                                            - tab.getMeasuredWidth());
                    }
                    for (int i = position + 1; i < count; i++) {
                            final TextView tab = (TextView) getChildAt(i);
                            if (i == position + 1) {
                                    tabPositions[i] = width - tab.getMeasuredWidth()
                                                    + tab.getPaddingRight();
                            } else {
                                    tabPositions[i] = width * 2;
                            }
                            final TextView prevTab = (TextView) getChildAt(i - 1);
                            tabPositions[i] = Math.max(tabPositions[i], tabPositions[i 
       - 1]
                                            + prevTab.getMeasuredWidth());
                    }
            } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < tabPositions.length; i++) {
                            tabPositions[i] = -1;
                    }
            }
    }

    /**
     * Update the ellipsize of the text views
     */
    private void updateEllipsize() {
            if (mAdapter == null) {
                    return;
            }

            final int count = mAdapter.getCount();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    TextView tab = (TextView) getChildAt(i);

                    if (i < mCurrentPos) {
                            tab.setEllipsize(null);
                            tab.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                    } else if (i == mCurrentPos) {
                            tab.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
                            tab.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                    } else if (i > mCurrentPos) {
                            tab.setEllipsize(null);
                            tab.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                    }
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

            measureTabs(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

            int height = 0;
            final View v = getChildAt(0);
            if (v != null) {
                    height = v.getMeasuredHeight();
            }

            setMeasuredDimension(
                            resolveSize(getPaddingLeft() + widthSize + 
   getPaddingRight(),
                                            widthMeasureSpec),
                            resolveSize(height + mBottomBarHeight + getPaddingTop()
                                            + getPaddingBottom(), heightMeasureSpec));

            if (mWidth != widthSize) {
                    mWidth = widthSize;
                    updateTabPositions(true);
            }
    }

    /**
     * Measure our tab text views
     *
     * @param widthMeasureSpec
     * @param heightMeasureSpec
     */
    private void measureTabs(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            if (mAdapter == null) {
                    return;
            }

            int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            final int maxWidth = (int) (widthSize * 0.6);

            final int count = mAdapter.getCount();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) getChildAt(i)
                                    .getLayoutParams();
                    final int widthSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(maxWidth,
                                    MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
                    final int heightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                                    layoutParams.height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
                    getChildAt(i).measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
            if (mAdapter == null) {
                    return;
            }

            final int count = mAdapter.getCount();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    View v = getChildAt(i);

                    v.layout(mCurrentTabPos[i], this.getPaddingTop(), mCurrentTabPos[i]
                                    + v.getMeasuredWidth(),
                                    this.getPaddingTop() + v.getMeasuredHeight());
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            if (mCurrentPos != -1) {
                    // calculate the relative position of the fronted tab to set the
                    // alpha channel of the tab indicator
                    final int tabSelectedTop = getHeight() - getPaddingBottom()
                                    - mBottomBarHeight - mTabIndicatorHeight;
                    final View currentTab = getChildAt(mCurrentPos);
                    final int centerOfTab = (mCurrentTabPos[mCurrentPos] + currentTab
                                    .getMeasuredWidth()) - 
            (currentTab.getMeasuredWidth() / 2);
                    final int center = getWidth() / 2;
                    final int centerDiv3 = center / 3;
                    final float relativePos = 1.0f - Math.min(
                                    Math.abs((float) (centerOfTab - center)
                                                    / (float) (centerDiv3)), 1.0f);

                    mCachedTabPaint.setAlpha((int) (255 * relativePos));
                    canvas.drawRect(
                                    mCurrentTabPos[mCurrentPos],
                                    tabSelectedTop,
                                    mCurrentTabPos[mCurrentPos] + 
  currentTab.getMeasuredWidth(),
                                    tabSelectedTop + mTabIndicatorHeight, 
     mCachedTabPaint);

                    // set the correct text colors on the text views
                    final int count = mAdapter.getCount();
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                            final TextView tab = (TextView) getChildAt(i);
                            if (mCurrentPos == i) {
                                    tab.setTextColor(interpolateColor(mBottomBarColor,
                                                    mTextColor, 1.0f - relativePos));
                            } else {
                                    tab.setTextColor(mTextColor);
                            }
                    }

            }

            super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.draw(canvas);

            // draw the bottom bar
            final int bottomBarTop = getHeight() - getPaddingBottom()
                            - mBottomBarHeight;
            mCachedTabPaint.setAlpha(0xff);
            canvas.drawRect(0, bottomBarTop, getWidth(), bottomBarTop
                            + mBottomBarHeight, mCachedTabPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected float getLeftFadingEdgeStrength() {
            // forced so that we will always have the left fading edge
            return 1.0f;
    }

    @Override
    protected float getRightFadingEdgeStrength() {
            // forced so that we will always have the right fading edge
            return 1.0f;
    }

    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }

    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                    int positionOffsetPixels) {
            if (mAdapter == null) {
                    return;
            }

            final int count = mAdapter.getCount();

            float x = 0.0f;
            int dir = 0;

            // detect the swipe direction
            if (positionOffsetPixels != 0 && mCurrentPos == position) {
                    dir = -1;
                    x = positionOffset;
            } else if (positionOffsetPixels != 0 && mCurrentPos != position) {
                    dir = 1;
                    x = 1.0f - positionOffset;
            }

            // update the current positions
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    final float curX = mFrontedTabPos[i];
                    float toX = 0.0f;

                    if (dir < 0) {
                            toX = mLeftTabPos[i];
                    } else if (dir > 0) {
                            toX = mRightTabPos[i];
                    } else {
                            toX = mFrontedTabPos[i];
                    }

                    final int offsetX = (int) ((toX - curX) * x + 0.5f);
                    final int newX = (int) (curX + offsetX);

                    mCurrentTabPos[i] = newX;
            }

            requestLayout();
            invalidate();
    }

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            mCurrentPos = position;
            updateTabPositions(false);
    }

    private int interpolateColor(final int color1, final int color2,
                    float fraction) {
            final float alpha1 = Color.alpha(color1) / 255.0f;
            final float red1 = Color.red(color1) / 255.0f;
            final float green1 = Color.green(color1) / 255.0f;
            final float blue1 = Color.blue(color1) / 255.0f;

            final float alpha2 = Color.alpha(color2) / 255.0f;
            final float red2 = Color.red(color2) / 255.0f;
            final float green2 = Color.green(color2) / 255.0f;
            final float blue2 = Color.blue(color2) / 255.0f;

            final float deltaAlpha = alpha2 - alpha1;
            final float deltaRed = red2 - red1;
            final float deltaGreen = green2 - green1;
            final float deltaBlue = blue2 - blue1;

            float alpha = alpha1 + (deltaAlpha * fraction);
            float red = red1 + (deltaRed * fraction);
            float green = green1 + (deltaGreen * fraction);
            float blue = blue1 + (deltaBlue * fraction);

            alpha = Math.max(Math.min(alpha, 1f), 0f);
            red = Math.max(Math.min(red, 1f), 0f);
            green = Math.max(Math.min(green, 1f), 0f);
            blue = Math.max(Math.min(blue, 1f), 0f);

            return Color.argb((int) (alpha * 255.0f), (int) (red * 255.0f),
                            (int) (green * 255.0f), (int) (blue * 255.0f));
    }

      }












                     public class SwipeyTabFragment extends Fragment {

    public static Fragment newInstance(String title) {
            SwipeyTabFragment f = new SwipeyTabFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("title", title);
            f.setArguments(args);
            return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_swipeytab, 
   null);
            final String title = getArguments().getString("title");
            ((TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(title);
            return root;
    }


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> just tell me how do i add activites in this application? is show same activity in all tabs

You don't. Having activities-in-tabs was deprecated well over two years ago.

A `ViewPager` typically uses fragments for its pages, as is demonstrated in the code you pasted above. In this sample, each page is a `SwipeyTabFragment`, but you are welcome to have pages be different fragment classes if you prefer. You are also welcome to not use fragments and use custom `Views` instead for the pages. But there is no support for putting activities as pages.

Comment: is there any example for playstore like tabbar?

Comment: @user2425717: Since the Play Store uses a `ViewPager`, much like what you have above, I do not know what you are looking for.

Comment: @user2425717: Their `PagerAdapter` returns different content for each page. In the sample you show above, `SwipeyTabsPagerAdapter` returns an instance of the same fragment class (`SwipeyTabFragment`) for each requested position. You are welcome to return instances of *different* fragment classes for each requested position, using conditional programming structures like `if` or `switch`.